# VB scripting in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

In my attribute tables field I am trying to get rid of the "&" in between names i.e. "John Adams & wife" and want it to say "John Adams and Wife" in all the attributes with "&".

What is the VB for that?

I can't seem to find it in the help page of ArcGIS.

Comment: vba and vbscript are different languages.  At 10.0 calculator supports vbscript and python.  Before 10.0 it supported VBA and vbscript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [the replace function in the calculate field examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000.htm). Something like this should do it:

```
NewString = Replace([comments], "&", "and")
```

Comment: Don't forget that doing this outside of an edit session will overwrite without undo. This solution will work right but you should test more complex calculations (on the containing field).

Comment: Thank You, I solved it late last night.  I was very close for a while then figured it out.